# Save query result from QGIS to csv

Tags: qgis, sql, dbmanager

I have a layer saved to spatialite which I want to query and save part of to csv.

Even the query result takes a very long time to load to the browser (2.5M rows) even if I load it without geometry.

Is there a way to use the SQL engine DB Manager has to save the query result to file?

I already tried the sqlite way with the example I found [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-export-csv/).
and the COPY TO way PostgreSQL uses specified [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html).

Is there another way I am missing? I thought QGIS DB Manager uses an SQLite engine.

Using QGIS 3.2.1 on Windows.

Comment: Did you you consider 'Extract by expression' processing algorithm from the processing toolbox and save its result directly to csv?

Comment: the file is too large to work with, that's why i'm using SQL. Other than exporting it to sqlite i couldn't do anything with the original layer. my problem is the fact that i don't have and can't install even sqlite itself on the machine that has to work with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @Jochen Schwarze's answer is good, it did not answer the question of how to perform an SQL query on the data.
since i don't have SQLite installed i used QGIS' python interpreter to read the data from the sqlite(spatialite, since geometry existed) file and write it to csv.

```
sqlite_file = 'path/to/test.sqlite'
csvfile = 'path/to/test.csv'

import sqlite3
import csv

conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
conn.enable_load_extansion(True)
conn.execute('SELECT load_extension("mod_spatialite")')
conn.execute('SELECT InitSpatialMetaData(1);')
c = conn.cursor()

data = c.cursor('select column1, column2, aswkt(GEOMETRY) geom from test;')

with open(csvfile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['column1','column2', 'geom'])
    writer.writerows(data)

conn.close()
```

this allowed me to read and convert the large file without having to add it to the workspace in QGIS.

Comment: Did you consider using sth like sqlite manager add on for Mozilla Firefox? With this you would not need the python interpreter or qgis at all anyway.

Comment: That would be problematic, as i have stated in my comment, i can't install new software on the machine since it's closed network. also i used QGIS to convert another, larger csv file to sqlite so i could work with it.

Answer (score 2):

I claim the key problem is to build the table view resulting from your query, not the query itself. '*Extract* by expression' algorithm in QGIS 3 is written as a native C++ algorithm and as such VERY FAST. In contrary to '*Select* by expression' you don't generate a selection in QGIS 3 and then 'Save layer...' with 'Save only selected objects' enabled. '*Extract* by expression' will save the query result directly to the format you desire which may take some time too as well, but you avoid creating a temporary table view in the attribute table or some query tool.

Comment: this was good and i did not know the tool, but i need to run a specific SQL query on the data and the python way solved it faster than rewriting the subset in the expression tool.